# How to get access/permission for sendMessage to send data from any web pages to background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, manifest

I'm building cross browser extention, and face problem, i can't send sendMessage from chrome without 'externally_connectable' and 'matches' in it.
google guide said i can't matche URLs like this "" or this  "http://*/*", only target URL like this: 'http://localhost:3000/', how avoid this and use 'runtime.sendMessage' from any web page?

**my inpage scrypt**

```
const ID = 'cb7b13f5efcbcc4453d4ebf63f7';

const send = (data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    extensionizer.runtime.sendMessage(ID, { method: 'send', data }, (res) => {
        if (res.error) reject(res.error);
        resolve(res);
    });
});
```

**my background scrypt**

```
const onExternalMessage = (request, sender, sendResponse) => {

    const id = Date.now();

    requestQueue.push({
        data: request.data, sender, id, cb: sendResponse,
    });

};
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "short_name": "Send",
  "name": "Sender",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "./index.html",
  },
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "file://*/*",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "./content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "inpage.js",
    "background.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's not clear why you need such a thing, but it's not possible anyway. If you want to expose your extension to the web pages you can do it via DOM CustomEvent API with listener(s) in your content script.

Comment: thx for the answer